# Uncaught Error: Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: laravel, vue.js

What is this errors? I use laravel.

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './files/home-style.css

app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('payment', require('./components/Payment.vue'));
Vue.component('form-ajax', require('./components/FormAjax.vue'));
Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

    Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

// Echo.private(`articles.admin`)
//     .listen('ArticleEvent', function(e)  {
//         console.log(e);
//     });
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx2Zi.png)

Comment: That error does not come from this file. Go to the file where you reference `./files/home-style.css` and make sure `home-style.css` is exactly where you think it is. If it is, double check.

Comment: I use phpstorm. And press Key Ctrl + Shift + N. and type home-style.css. This file does not exist

Comment: Search the whole codebase looking for `home-style.css`. This file is being referenced but does not exist. Find and remove the reference if you no longer need it?